# HTML 5 toggling the contenteditable attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, contenteditable

`enter code here`I am trying to make something editable online with a function like this

```
function toggle_editable (div, cssclass) {

var classToEdit = document.getElementsByClassName(cssclass)

    for (i = 0;classToEdit.length; i++) {

        if (classToEdit[i].contentEditable == false) {
            classToEdit[i].contentEditable = true ;
        }
        if (classToEdit[i].contentEditable == true) {
            classToEdit[i].contentEditable = false ;
        }
    }
}
```

classToEdit is a collection of HTML elements with the same class name or whatever document.getElementsByClassName(cssclass) returns

when going through the debugger it jumps over the line

```
classToEdit[i].contentEditable == true
```

as well as over the line

```
 classToEdit[i].contentEditable == true
```

and does not execute the code in the braces following the `if` statements

this works however - meaning it sets the contenteditable property without hesitation

`classToEdit.contenteditable = true;`

as well as this

```
classToEdit.contenteditable = false;
```

(well obviously)

also this seemed to have no effect

```
classToEdit.contenteditable = !classToEdit.contenteditable
```

ideas anyone?

ps why is the loop

Comment: In addition to the first answer, you also need `else if` instead of just `if`…

Comment: Again, if  `classToEdit` is a HTMLCollection, setting `classToEdit.contenteditable = true` definitely doesn't change the `contentEditable` value of an element.

Comment: Also, if you want to toggle the value of contentEditable, you could do so using `element.contentEditable = !(element.contentEditable);`. No need for an `if` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an infinite loop here:

```
for (i = 0;classToEdit.length; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < classToEdit.length; i++) {
```

But, if you say `classToEdit.contenteditable = true` "works", you've to define "not working/is working" since the snippet  doesn't definitely do what you expect it to do, if `classToEdit` is a HTMLCollection.

It looks like you'd want to toggle `contentEditable` values, you can do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < classToEdit.length; i++) {
    if (classToEdit[i].contentEditable == false) {
        classToEdit[i].contentEditable = true ;
    } else { // Notice else here, no need for another check
        classToEdit[i].contentEditable = false;
    }
}
```

Or simply without `if`s in the loop:

```
classToEdit[i].contentEditable = !classToEdit[i].contentEditable;
```

Your current code will switch the value back to it's original in a case the value was `false`.

Comment: Worked - thanks for your support and to teemu for the infinite loop note.

Comment: @KirilIliev Well, that might have been a typo in the post only, but I mentioned it just in case it isn't a typo. An answer to the "ps" question you can find from the documentation of [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Also note `i` should be declared.

Answer (score 0):

[`HTMLElement.contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable) returns a string and not a boolean.

Hence, what you want to identify the state of your editable field is:

```
// Incorrect
classToEdit[i].contentEditable == true
// Coorect
classToEdit[i].contentEditable === 'true'
```

What's even better if you want to know the state of your fields is to use [`HTMLElement.isContentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.isContentEditable)
 which returns a boolean:

```
classToEdit[i].contentEditable = !element.isContentEditable
```

Another way to refactor the above:

```
function toggleContentEdit() {
    var editableFields = document.getElementsByClassName('editable');

    [].forEach.call(editableFields, function(field){
        var isEditable = field.isContentEditable;
        field.setAttribute('contenteditable', !isEditable);
    });
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qz3aotv/

Comment: `Element.contentEditable` is the same as using `get/setAttribute('contenteditable')`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable)

Comment: That's interesting, booleans have always worked for me.

Comment: Yeah - I always thought javascript was a C++ with loose rules - it turns out it has stricter rules and not so straightforward typecasting :)